# induction, recursive function, discrete mathematics

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, induction, recursion

Please help solve following recursive function. How can I solve $n-10$ for $M(99)$ or $M(98)$ if $n>100$ ? :

> Find $M(99), M(100)$, and $M(98)$ when
>
> $$  M(n) = \begin{cases} n-10,  & \text{if $n>100$} \\ M(M(n + 11)), &
>  \text{if $n \le 100$} \end{cases}$$
>   for all positive integers $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$M(100)=M(M(100+11))$$
$$=M(M(111))$$
$$=M(111-10)$$
$$=M(101)$$
$$=101-10$$
$$=91$$

$$M(99)=M(M(99+11))$$
$$=M(M(110))$$
$$=M(110-10)$$
$$=M(100)$$
$$=91$$

$$M(98)=M(M(98+11))$$
$$=M(M(109))$$
$$=M(109-10)$$
$$=M(99)$$
$$=91$$

Comment: Thank you so much! It is much more clear now. However why do we deduct 10 twice here?:                                   =M(111−10)
=M(101)
=101−10

Comment: @NadiaS: That is because I used the second rule twice: first, to go from $M(M(111))$ to $M(111-10)$, since $111>100$; second, to go from $M(101)$ to 101-10, since $101>100$. In the first, note that the key is going from $M(111)$ to $111-10$; there is another $M()$ around those. Is it clear now?